# How to make Nginx redirect 301 302 307 to new URL on same server

Tags: nginx

I have tried multiple suggestions on this to no avail. I am trying to perform a redirect when a proxy request to a client returns a 307. I am picking up the new endpoint to send to from the Location header of the response from the upstream client, and presumably setting it as the new endpoint to send to, then sending it back to the same client but over a different endpoint. But my issue is I can't seem to initiate a second redirect since I can't see any going out from nginx or hitting the upstream client.

The necessary part of my Nginx config is as below:

```
            #staging server
            location /staging/mmcallback {
                    allow                   127.0.0.1/32;
                    allow                   XXXX;
                    allow                   XXXX;
                    deny                    all;
                    proxy_buffer_size   64k;
                    proxy_buffers       8 64k;
                    proxy_busy_buffers_size 128k;
                    proxy_http_version  1.1;
                    proxy_set_header    Connection "";
                    proxy_set_header    Host "YYYY.com";
                    proxy_pass      https://staging/mmcallback;
                    proxy_intercept_errors  on;
                    error_page 301 302 307 = @handle_redirects_staging;
            }

            #handle redirects for staging environment on client error
            location @handle_redirects_staging {
                    set $saved_location '$upstream_http_location';
                    proxy_http_version  1.1;
                    proxy_pass_request_body on;
                    proxy_pass      https://staging$saved_location;
            }
```

`staging` is an already defined upstream server config. I want a config such that when the first location returns a 301/2/7, it redirects to a second endpoint on same server returned in the Location header. Is there a config am missing? Or anything at all?

Edit:
Am seeing the below warning on Nginx logs, hope it helps?:

```
2020/09/09 12:19:56 [warn] 963#0: *1 upstream server temporarily disabled while connecting to upstream, client: X.X.X.X, server: _, request: "POST /staging/mmcallback/endpoint HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://[IPV6::99]:443/mmcallback/endpoint", host: "Y.Y.Y.Y:8443"
```

Sensitive data masked

Comment: I have no idea if this is a good suggestion, but you could use errorpages with just http meta refresh to the other page :))))

Comment: @Orphans I can't touch the other end, I have no access to it. Also, its a server to server call with Nginx in the middle, no UIs involved

Comment: Why do you want nginx to fetch the new URI? This is the job of the client.

Comment: @MichaelHampton nginx is the client in this scenario. The general layout is `API <-> Nginx <-> Target server`. For the above specific scenario, the flow is `API -> Nginx -> Target server`, and the issue is from `Nginx -> Target` server where the target server returns the 301/2/7 and Nginx has to fetch/follow that

Comment: No, I mean the real client, not nginx.

Comment: Oh, that was my initial design, which was the client to return the "next" URL which Nginx was supposed to follow to deliver the payload. Guess that didn't work. Allow me to ask, how would you have done it with the flow above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up refactoring the code on the upstream client to perform an internal "redirect" i.e. without returning a redirect http code to Nginx, so Nginx config remains the same as of now and redirects are occurring internally upstream.

Answer (score 0):

Is the nginx directive [`proxy_redirect`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect) any use here?

So if your proxy was returning a `301` to `http://example.com/redirect` and you wanted this to really go to `https://example2.com/hello`, you'd have an entry of:

```
proxy_redirect http://example.com/redirect https://example2.com/hello;
```

Comment: I tried this, did not work. I am beginning to think its more a limitation of Nginx than a config issue

Comment: What's the redirection URL that your proxy is returning? Can you give me an example?

Comment: using your example above, the same except with an IPV6 address resolved from the domain name e.g. https://[IPV6_ADDRESS]/hello, and thats it. It doesn't continue from there. I tried testing with a curl request, and the curl request failed, so I think thats the cause. Am using a GCE VM for context